# vue.js form submit did not get the new value of model-bind

Tags: vue.js

I have a form

HTML:

```
<form ref="myForm" action="/AAA/BBB" method="get">
   <input type="text" hidden="hidden" v-model="myValue" name="myName" />
</form>
<button v-on:click="Send">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
   data: {
      myValue: 1
   },
   methods: {
      Send: function() {
         this.myValue = 2;
         this.$refs.myForm.submit();
      }
   }
})
```

When i click the button, it will send the value: 1

I'm sure that the value was modified before form submit

Comment: You're not reading the value from the query parameters in any way so the value you specify in code will be used instead.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I do not understand what the comments you leaved, the input will binding with the model myValue

Comment: Yes, it will. Then you send your form which will cause a reload of the page and everything will be reset.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen But the other input of this form(did not show in the sample) also binding with other models, they actually send the modified value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you set the value of a data property in a Vue instance's method, any elements bound with `v-model` will not update until the method has completed.

In your case, the bound input has not updated with the new value of `myValue` when you access the form and submit it.

To get around this, you can use the `Vue.nextTick` method, available on each Vue instance via `this.$nextTick`. This method allows you to pass a callback to execute once the Vue instance's template has finished updating.

In your case, you could do this:

```
Send: function() {
  this.myValue = 2;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.myForm.submit();
  });
}
```